# How to set up python-telegram-bot webhook on Heroku?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using the python-telegram-bot wrapper, and I've been trying to host a simple echo telegram bot on Heroku [adapting a pre-existing example](https://github.com/sooyhwang/Simple-Echo-Telegram-Bot/blob/master/bot.py) that was meant for the Google App Engine as well as the [webhook guide on the wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku), but to no avail.

I do not seem to be able to get the webhook to work, and for the bot to echo messages correctly.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, so any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

My attempt is detailed below.

```
import telegram
from os import environ
from telegram.ext import Updater
from flask import Flask, request
from credentials import TOKEN, APP_URL

app = Flask(__name__)

global bot
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)


@app.route('/' + TOKEN, methods=['POST'])
def webhook_handler():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # retrieve the message in JSON and then transform it to Telegram object
        update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True))

        chat_id = update.message.chat.id

        # Telegram understands UTF-8, so encode text for unicode compatibility
        text = update.message.text.encode('utf-8')

        # repeat the same message back (echo)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)

    return 'ok'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PORT = int(environ.get('PORT', '5000'))
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    # add handlers
    updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0", port=PORT, url_path=TOKEN)
    updater.bot.setWebhook(APP_URL + TOKEN)
    updater.idle()
    app.run(environ.get('PORT'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the wiki you'll find the easiest example.

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku

In short, do not try to use flask. Use the built-in webserver.